# Undefined team_id in BoltJs event

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-bolt

I'm trying to handle the situation when my Slack app (built on top of BoltJS) is removed from a workspace, in order to remove its record from the database.

Here is the section that handles it:

```js
app.event('app_uninstalled', async({team_id}) => {
    await db.removeTeam(team_id);
    await http.delete(`${constants.BASE_URL}?teamId=${team_id}`);
});
```

However, the `team_id` value that is supposed to come from Slack is `undefined`. I also checked the [Slack docs](https://api.slack.com/events/app_uninstalled) and it seems I should be looking at the `team_id` parameter, which I do.

I would appreciate any help to see what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The `team_id` parameter should be accessed from the `body` object, therefore:

```js
app.event('app_uninstalled', async({body}) => {
    await db.removeTeam(body.team_id);
    await http.delete(`${constants.BASE_URL}?teamId=${body.team_id}`);
});
```